# Diodes made using separate p and n-type semiconductors

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

Can a diode be made by connecting, in series, separate n and p-type semiconductors?

Assume that all ends are attached to Ohmic contacts. I am hoping that this will prevent any discontinuities in the potential.

I have seen a similar question on the Physics Stack Exchange, but the question is too old to make comments (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72432/would-connecting-p-type-and-n-type-semiconductors-work-as-a-diode). But in that question, they didn't talk about Ohmic contacts.

[image: Hypothetical Diode]

Comment: No, you need P and N doped stuff to physically touch. There forms a barrier.

Comment: @Ilya What difference does it make if ohmic contacts are present. The potential at the end of the p-side will continue at the start of the n-side right?

Comment: Where P and N regions touch, there appears a "neutral" zone, small layer of "undoped" (electrically-neutral more like) area that actually forms the barrier. If I simplify it a bit, it's kinda like P and N regions diffuse into one another a little and that forms the barrier. If there is distance between them, it won't work. There are a lot of materials that explain physics inside diodes in relatively simple words (like me but actually correct and smart)

Comment: @Ilya So, what about the cases where we (in UG courses) assume PN-junction diodes to have abrupt junctions? (an ideal diode)

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull That's what Ilya means by simplifying it a bit. The dopants don't diffuse between them, the charge carriers do, and they neutralize to an extent.

Comment: @Hearth I still cannot understand it. If an abrupt junction diode can behave like a normal diode, then why can't the circuit drawn work like one? The minority and the majority carriers can still pass onto the two regions right?

Comment: You'll have recombination at your ohmic contacts.

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull No, they can't. Holes can't travel through metal, they recombine with electrons immediately.

Comment: @Hearth This explains everything. Is it possible for you to write an answer including all these things? It would be very much useful for students like me.

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull I'm afraid I don't have the time right now, but if I remember and no one else does, I'll write one up after work.

Comment: @Hearth I really appreciate your help. I will leave this question open.

Comment: The question may be old, but it does answer the question in the first line. *A pn junction is **one piece** of a semiconductor that receives n-type doping in one section and p-type doping in an adjacent section. If you simply stick two p-type and n-type semiconductors to each other by hand, it will not behave as a diode.*

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat There are mixed answers in that post. Some say about the possibility of using special contacts to make the above setup behave like a diode. I just wanted to know whether this can be achieved using ohmic contacts. If you know the answer, please try to write a detailed answer explaining this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a diode be made by connecting, in series, separate n and p-type semiconductors?

**No.** What you show would behave as 2 resistors in series.

Note that PN junctions in a semiconductor rely on dopings **within the same crystal structure**, i.e. [monocrystalline silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monocrystalline_silicon).

Your picture shows two independent crystals.

Comment: But, what about the ohmic contacts?

Comment: they're just that – ohmic contacts. What you've drawn is really just two separate resistors. (and that's good! Though experiment: we both agree the contact-P+-contact component doesn't *do* anything special, right? so, why should the whole thing suddenly behave differently when, 2km down the cable, someone attaches a contact-n-contact component?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you mean to say that the device will behave like a  diode?

Comment: no, the opposite.